# How to post a file by cUrl method in yii2

Tags: php, curl, yii2

I will attach a file from a controller and it done

```
 $filePath = Yii::getAlias("@backend/web/uploads/".$filename);
```

after add this file it post to a action url. I try to use

```
    $request = curl_init($url_path);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt(
        $request,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        array(
            'filedata' => $file_path
        ));


    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

But it's not working. I need solution on yii2

Answer (score 0):

You should use **'file' => '@'** and **curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);**

**Working and tested example** on PHP 5.6+:

Server-side (index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
        <input type="file" name="myf" id="myf">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Server-side (upload.php):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo $_FILES["myf"]["tmp_name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myf"]["tmp_name"], 'f.dat');

?>
```

Client-side (curl-test.php), that you need:

```
<?php

$args['myf'] = '@/Users/Oleg/Temp/curl-test-php/example.txt';

$request = curl_init('http://domain.ru/upload/upload.php');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);

?>
```

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload
about CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD and right way to use not deprecated methods if you need safe solution

Comment: it does not working if i add @ at first of the file path

Comment: What do you use 'file' or 'filedata' in array as a key?

Comment: In 5.6, @ option will be switched off by default. Thus just add false setting for CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD. I'm sure, that it is working. I made for you clear plain php example and tested on my server. All is OK. File transferred and saved with "Deprecated: curl_setopt(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead in /Users/oleg/Temp/curl-test-php/curl-test.php on line 13". But working!

Comment: I reloaded my answer. Get it! )